# Mixture os $W$ boson with charged Goldstone boson

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

Is a propagator like this possible in the Standard Model?

[image]

In fact, there is a term of the form $i m_W (W_{\mu}^- \partial ^\mu \varphi^+ - W_{\mu}^+ \partial ^\mu \varphi^-)$ in the Lagrangian so this propagator should be possible. However I have nerver seen any diagram with it.

Comment: If my memory is correct, these types of diagrams are canceled out when working in the $R_\xi$ gauge. Can you give us a link to the lagrangian where you saw this term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a propagator but a vertex since it is composed of more than one field. Usually, these vertices are canceled out when working in the $R_\xi$ gauge :

Take your lagrangian density expressed in terms of $Z, W^+, W^-$, and $A$, and do the inverse of the following change:
\begin{equation}
    W^\pm_\mu\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(W^1_\mu \mp iW^2_\mu)\,\,\,,\,\,\,
    \left( 
    \begin{array}{c}
    Z^0_\mu \\
    A_\mu
    \end{array}
    \right)
    \equiv
    \left( 
    \begin{array}{cc}
    \cos \theta_W & -\sin \theta_W \\
    \sin \theta_W & \cos \theta_W
    \end{array}
    \right)
    \left( 
    \begin{array}{c}
    W^3_\mu \\
    B_\mu
    \end{array}
    \right)
\end{equation}
Now you can write your lagrangian density in terms of $A^\#$ ($\#=1,2,3,Y)$, where $A^{1,2,3}=W^{1,2,3}$ and $A^Y=B$. Moreover you can decompose the Higgs doublet as $\phi_0+\chi$, where $\phi_0$ is the vacuum expectation value and $\chi$ is a doublet containing the Higgs and the Goldstone bosons. The lagrangian density is then:
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{2} A^\#_\mu (-\eta^{\mu \nu} \square +\partial^\mu \partial^\nu)A^\#_\nu+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \chi)^\dagger(\partial^\mu \chi)+g\partial^\mu \chi_i A^\#_\mu F^\#_i+\frac{1}{2}m^2_{\# \sharp} A^\#_\mu A^{\sharp,\mu}-\frac{1}{2} M_{ij} \chi_i \chi_j
\end{equation*}
The third term in the right-hand-side is the term you are describing. Where the matrix $F_i$ can be viewed as the square-root of the mass matrix:
\begin{equation}
    m^2_{\#,\sharp} = g^2 F^\#_j F^\sharp_j\,\,\,,\,\,\,gF^\#_j=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}
    \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    g & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & g & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & g \\
    0 & 0 & -g'
    \end{array}
    \right).
\end{equation}
The partition function of the system is:
\begin{equation*}
    Z=\int \mathcal{D} A \mathcal{D}\chi e^{i\int d^4 x \mathcal{L}[A,\chi]}
\end{equation*}
Then, for working in the $R_\xi$ gauge, you use the following function $G$ for gauge fields interacting with scalar fields:
\begin{equation}
    G^\#=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi}}\left( \partial_\mu A^{\#,\mu}-\xi gF^\#_i \chi_i \right)
\end{equation}
and apply the Fadeev-Popov method that leads to the partition function:
\begin{equation*}
    Z \propto \int \mathcal{D} A \mathcal{D}\chi \left[ i \int d^4x \left( \mathcal{L}[A,\chi]-\frac{1}{2}G^\# G^\#\right) \right] \text{det}\left( \frac{\delta G}{\delta \alpha} \right)
\end{equation*}
The new lagrangian density is therefore:
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}'=-\frac{1}{2} A^\#_\mu \left( \left[ -\eta^{\mu \nu} \square +\left(1-\frac{1}{\xi} \right)\partial^\mu \partial^\nu \right]\delta^{\# \sharp}-g^2F^\#_i F^\sharp_i \eta^{\mu \nu}\right) A^\sharp_\nu+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \chi)^\dagger (\partial^\mu \chi)-\frac{1}{2}\xi g^2 F^\#_i F^\#_j \chi_i \chi_j
\end{equation}
And we see that the terms you are describing vanished. The complete lagrangian density of the standard model is not written in the $R_\xi$ gauge, so this is the reason you see such diagrams in it, however we usually work in this gauge, so this is why you have never seen these (but Peskin and Schroeder describe them page 691, Eq. 20.10, for example).